# One angular app inside another

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

is there a possibility to have one angularjs app inside another? For example if I have one app that switches route(using ui-router) and another app which works when I go into this route.

Comment: Why would you need to do this? Intent is not clear. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @charlietfl, Hi, I have one main app and it has a lot of services and controllers, and I have another part which also depends on a lot of services, so I`d like to separate this parts. Do you think It's a bad idea?Thanks.

Comment: @charlietfl, I`m new to angular and dont know a lot of features, so maybe you can give me some advice

Comment: Can have multiple modules in one app